# On generalized fitting subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

I can't understand so much the second paragraph (page 160) of the proof of the lemma 31.17(1) (pages 160) in M. Aschbacher, *Finite Group Theory* about generalized fitting subgroup. Here I post the statement of the lemma and the proof given in the book.

**(31.17)** Let $O_{p'}(G)=1$ and $P$ a $p$-subgroup of $G$ where $p$ is a prime. Then

(1) $O_{p',E}(N_G(P))$ fixes each component of $G$.

**Proof** Let $H=N_G(P)$, $X=O_{p'}(H)$, $H^*=H/X$. Let 
  $K\leq X$ or $X\leq H$ with $K^*\in Comp(H^*)$, and subject to these constraints 
pick $K$ minimal subject to moving a component of $G$. Let $P\leq P_0\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(C_G(K))$. 
As $K$ satisfies the same hypothesis with respect to $P_0$, we 
may take $P = P_0$. In particular, by 31.14, $O_p(G) \leq P$. 
Let $R\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H \cap E(G))$.

Suppose first $K\leq X$. Then $K$ is a $q$-group for some prime $q$, and by 
coprime action, 18.7, 
**there exists an $R$-invariant Sylow $q$-group $Q$ of $O_{p'}(H)$ containing $K$.** 
By 24.4, $Q = [R, Q]C_Q(R)$. Now $[R, Q] \leq [E(G), Q] \leq E(G)$, 
so $[R,Q]$ fixes each component of $G$. Hence we may take $[K, R] = 1$. 
**Thus, by choice of $P,~R\leq P$. So $P\cap E(H)\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$ by Exercise 3.2.**
As $O_{p'}(G) = 1$, $p\in\pi(L)$ for each $L\in Comp(G)$, so $1\neq P \cap L\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(L)$ by 6.4. 
Then $P\cap L\nleq Z(L)$, so $L= [E(G), P\cap L]$ is $K$-invariant. 
$\cdots\cdots\cdots$

- From my perspective, I guess $K$ is $R$-invariant. But why?
- Why $P\cap E(H)\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$?
- Why pick such $R$?

Here some definitions.

- The *components* of a group $G$ are its subnormal quasisimple subgroups.
  $Comp(G)$ is the set of components of $G$. And $E(G)=\langle Comp(G)\rangle$, $F^*(G)=F(G)E(G)$.
- For a set of primes $\pi$. $O_{\pi}(G)$ is the maximal normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$, $O^{\pi}(G)$ is the minimal normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient group is a $\pi$-group. And $O_{p',E}(G)/O_{p'}(G)=E(G/O_{p'}(G))$.

**(31.14)** Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then

(1) $O_{p',E}(G)\leq C_G(O_p(G))$, and

(2) If $P\leq O_p(G)$ then $O^p(F^*(N_G(P))) = O^p(F^*(G))$.

**Exercise 3.2** Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then
$P\in\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$ or $P<P_0\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(N_G(P))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is hard to read!

I am not sure why $K$ is $R$-invariant, but  the $R$-invariant Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ contains a conjugate of $K$, so we can just replace $K$ by that conjugate to get $K \le Q$.

I can't make much sense of $P \cap E(H) \le {\rm Syl}_p(H)$, and I suspect that was not exactly what he meant, so let's ignore that and carry on reading.

Since $R \le P$, we have $R = P \cap E(G)$. Then we must have $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(PE(G)$, since otherwise $N_G(P) \cap E(G)$ would  strictly contain $R$, contradicting $R \in {\rm Syl}_p(H \cap E(G))$. So $P \cap E(G) \in {\rm Syl}_p(E(G)$ and hence also $P \cap L \in {\rm Syl}_p(L)$. Note also that $P \cap L \le R$ is centralized by $K$, and so it is $K$-invariant.

I everything else OK for that case?

Comment: If K is not R-invariant, why [K,R]=1 in line 4 of the second paragraph of the proof. @Derek Holt

Comment: It is true that Q always contains a conjugate of K. But what if Q is the smallest R-invariant q-subgroup and K<Q? It might happen. Right? Then K might not be R-invariant. @Derek Holt

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment. There is no claim in the proof that $K$ is $R$-invariant, only that $Q$ is an invariant Sylow $q$-subgroup containing $K$. I think what is happening here is that, since $[R,Q]$ fixes each component and $Q=[R,Q]C_Q(R)$, we can choose a new $K$ with $K \le C_Q(R)$.

Comment: Since $K$ is cyclic in this case, and let $K=\langle x\rangle$, we have $x=ab$ where $a\in [R,Q]$ and $b\in C_Q(R)$. So $x$ moves some component if and only if $b$ moves some component. And we may substitute $K$ by $\langle b\rangle\leq C_Q(R)$. Now I get it. Thanks for your patient. @Derek Holt